# How to access my .png from a folder using CSS?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a folder called "Images" inside my IDE and I want to access this file for my CSS property background-repeat:repeat;

How do I "call" it?

images/background.png isn't working! :(

EDIT: Here's the solution showing the hierarchy. Any help? :)

[image: http://i32.tinypic.com/2mnkqvd.png]

EDIT3:

I've got this now on my CSS:

```
body
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;    
    background-image: ../../Images/BackgroundPatternAlt.png;
    background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

According to my solution explorer picture, it should work but it isn't. Any help?

ps. To clarify my CSS can modify my page properly because if I change the background-color, everything changes properly. The error must be inside the background-image address. T_T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background images you define inside CSS is always relative to the path of the CSS (if you do not explicitly say not to).

So, if you want to use:

```
background: url(images/background.png) repeat;
```

...the CSS-file must be located in the "parent"/root of the images-folder, so I suggest you move the Images folder into App_Themes/Default.

Comment: Note the `url(...)`, it looks like you've forgotten that important piece.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. I actually think he should move the Image-folder into the App_Themes/Default so I'll leave it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Depends where the css file is in relation to the image. Is the .css file in a folder off the root? If so try "../images/background.png"

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your web-server, pathnames can be case sensitive, so it would be:

```
Images/background.png
```

**Edit:** If your Images folder is in the document root of the web-server, you can always use:

```
/Images/background.png
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see the picture, you must try yet another level up, at this path: `../../../Images/`

Answer (score 0):

Try '../../images/background.png' if the folder structure remains the same as in your Solution Explorer.